# Is it possible to make an inline call to another java atomic web service?

Tags: java, web-services

*Service A* will call the *Service B* for validating some number. Both *service A* and *B* are java atomic web service.
Is it feasible to make inline call to *service B* from *service A* for validating number through Datapower WSEL layer?

**Environment: J2EE, cxf, Datapower XI50, Weblogic**